# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Cron Jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, laravel-5.3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using ElasticBeanstalk for our application so that we can have it automatically scale with traffic.  Currently we only have the need for a single cron job to run nightly at 3am and I am trying to get it to work through the use of `.ebextensions`.

I have the following in a conjob.config file and it is being executed because I can go to the server and `cat /etc/cron.d/daily_snapshots`.

```
files:
    "/etc/cron.d/daily_snapshots":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        * * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

However, the cronjob is not executing on the schedule that I have set because the database records are not being updated.  I have run the command manually on the EC2 instance and it runs just fine.

We are using Laravel 5.3 so this is how I have the cron scheduled to run.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('ryno:compile-daily-snapshots')->dailyAt('03:00')->sendOutputTo(storage_path().'/logs/cron.log');
}
```

As stated it will run when I execute the exact same command that is in the cron file but it will not execute automatically when the cron runs.

We currently only have a single instance and I have read today that doing the cronjob in this manner is not a good idea because when another instance is spun up it would execute the cronjob for each EC2 instance in the environment.

I have read that I should use the leader_only setting and set it to true but I have also read that there are issues with that since the leader can change.

I know that I could spin up a worker instance and have that run the cron but with a single cron it seems like a large waste of resources.

How do you manage your cronjobs on your ElasticBeanstalk environment and which way would you suggest we take for this path?

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `root` in your crontab entry - I believe it should just read `* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. To help you debug, you could set `MAILTO=my_email@server.com` and/or send your output to a log file instead of to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I removed the second root but the cron is still not running per the schedule :(  I can set the MAILTO env variable but I am not sure how I would set the cron to use mailto, I will look into that and see if I can get it completed.

Comment: `MAILTO` isn't an environment variable - just add `MAILTO=joseph@domain.com` at the top of the crontab file.

Comment: I have added that and removed the >> /dev/null 2>&1 but I am not receiving any emails. It would appear that the cron is not running at all on the EC2 instance through ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: If you run `ps aux | grep crond` on the EC2 instance, does anything show up?

Comment: Yes it does.

$ ps aux | grep crond
root      1534  0.0  0.4 121628  2520 ?        Ss   May23   0:33 crond
ec2-user  6975  0.0  0.3 110464  2176 pts/0    S+   14:59   0:00 grep --color=auto crond

Comment: cron is definitely running then (which is what I would have expected.) Only other suggestion I can think of is to send output to a log file instead of `/dev/null` - something like `* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`. Cron jobs can be difficult to set up but it often comes down to environment variables, paths, and the like.

Comment: Will try this now and report back with the results.

Comment: I tried this with EveryFiveMinutes as the interval in Laravel Scheduling but there is no cron file created at all in /tmp